# ValueChangeEvent not fired when i click directly on a button

Tags: java, gwt

I have a text box with a valuechange handler :

```
@UiHandler("box")
public void box_onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
  window.alert("allright");
}
```

It works great if i lose focus by clicking elsewhere. Except when i click on a button.

Is there a trick i didn't see ? Should i hack my onclick event to fire the valuechangeevent anyway ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this specific do a browser? to dev mode vs. prod mode ?

Comment: oh, i imagined it was independant from the environment. I tested it prod-mode on chrome. I'll check with other.

Comment: Also, is this a `Button` or some `CustomButton`?

Comment: no, no. g:Button plain and simple

Comment: ah, it works with firefox. dev mode and prod mode

Comment: Do you reproduce in Chrome at http://jsfiddle.net/e5JQr/1/ (I can't reproduce with the dev-channel)

Comment: Ok, i spotted the difference. My button is disabled when the problem occur. With firefox, the onchange is fired anyway, with chrome it isn't.

Comment: Well, when the button is disabled, in Chrome, the textbox doesn't lose the focus, so it' expected that it doesn't fire an event.